# zend framework this->url get different url on the same page but different url

Tags: zend-framework, url

in application\modules\admin\layouts\scripts\layout.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->url(array('action'=>'logout','controller'=>'user','module'=>'admin'),null,true);?>
```

when I visited zfmul/public/admin-cate/ , It return

```
/zfmul/public/admin-cate/logout
```

but when I visited zfmul/public/admin/categories, It return

```
/zfmul/public/admin/user/logout
```

and the two url is render to the same module, same controller, same action, I wonder why it retrun different result?

I didi some configs in application.ini,

```
resources.router.routes.admincategories.route = "admin-cate/:action/:id"
resources.router.routes.admincategories.defaults.module = "admin"
resources.router.routes.admincategories.defaults.controller = "categories"
resources.router.routes.admincategories.defaults.action = "index"
resources.router.routes.admincategories.reqs.action = "save|edit|index|new"
resources.router.routes.admincategories.defaults.id = "1"
resources.router.routes.admincategories.reqs.id = "\d+"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$this->url`, you're in fact using `function url` from **library/Zend/View/Helper/Url.php**, whose 1st line is:

```
$router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
```

Since you declared a custom `admincategories` route, you now have 2 to access those particular module/controller/actions:

- Default - accessible via `zfmul/public/admin/categories`;
- Custom - accessible via `zfmul/public/admin-cate/`.

Depending on the URL you use to access, the `$router` variable value will change accordingly and so will the result of the `$this->url` call as you're experiencing.

Here are a few references to questions on SO that might help you work around that behaviour:

- [Zend Framework: How to disable default routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797279/zend-framework-how-to-disable-default-routing);
- [Zend framework: Removing default routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421334/zend-framework-removing-default-routes).